# Squid not caching static content

Tags: proxy, squid, cache

By looking to `Squid3` logs, I've found that Squid it's not caching static resources, for example:

```
1379041607.923    611 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/304 356 GET http://www.deckle.co.uk/squid-users-guide/css/site.css - DIRECT/95.172.21.186 -
```

The request for that css returns a `TCP_MISS` (even after reloading), and the same is happening for images, javascripts, htmls, etc. In fact, almost all requests got `TCP_MISS` with the exception of a very few.

If we look at the headers that deckle.co.uk, we see that it should be caching it:

```
$ http http://www.deckle.co.uk/squid-users-guide/css/site.css 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 482
Content-Type: text/css
Date: Fri, 13 Sep 2013 03:07:09 GMT
ETag: "d6007-30e-4d2a2f615c780"
Expires: Fri, 20 Sep 2013 03:07:09 GMT
Last-Modified: Sun, 06 Jan 2013 18:34:22 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

My config file contains:

```
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1    
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT    
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager    
http_access deny !Safe_ports    
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
http_port 3128     
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow all
cache_dir ufs /var/cache/squid3 10000 16 256
```

What am I missing? Why am I getting so much `TCP_MISS` and squid is not even caching static resources?

Comment: You should try use nginx instead as a caching reverse proxy. Far saner.

Answer (score 1):

The remote web server returned HTTP 304 (Not Modified). This means the *browser* already had a cached copy, and the server instructed the browser to use it, and didn't send a new copy. Therefore there was nothing for squid to cache.

Comment: what about `TCP_MISS/200 6578 GET http://www.deckle.co.uk/squid-users-guide/js/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js`? That returns 200 and doesnt gets cached either.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious. Where is your `cache.log`? Also check `store.log`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same behaviour with Squid 3.3.8 (package up to date on Ubuntu 14.10 at the time of writing)

After digging [here](http://bugs.squid-cache.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3806), I found out that the cache mishandling of CSS and JS when the Vary Header is present was effectively a bug, fixed in posterious releases.

Installing Squid 3.4.10 from the sources, makes disapear this issue.